# Ionic React useState value dissapears after using in a prop function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

so my usestate hook prints nothing after using it in a parent , im not sure about importing types in typescript since i just move from javascript.

```
    interface Props {
    sendTextMessage: (text?: string) => void
}

const Chatbar: React.FC<Props> = ({ sendTextMessage }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState<string>()

    return (

                        <IonInput
                            class='input'
                            value={text}
                            placeholder='Aa'
                            onIonChange={(e) => setText(e.detail.value!)}
                            onKeyPress={(event) => {
                                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                                    sendTextMessage(text)
                                    setText('')
                                }
                            }}
                            // clearInput
                        ></IonInput>
                
    )

}
```

the parent function

```
function sendTextMessage(message) {
    console.log(message)

    const messageEvent = {
        type: 'message',
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        source: {
            type: room?.get('type'),
            conId: room?.get('id'),
            userId: 'me',
        },
        message: {
            type: 'text',
            text: message,
        },
    }
```

---

```
<Chatbar sendTextMessage={sendTextMessage} />
```

i have also tried using another state in the parent file and that did nothing!!! i have no idea what i am doing wrong

Comment: Does it log correctly in `sendTextMessage`? Can you provide a running codesandbox that reproduces the issue and link here?

Comment: yes it does log correctly eveyrhting else does.. i have no idea how to make a code sandbox

Comment: Copy/paste your code into a new workspace from a react template, or if you've a github repo you can import directly. https://codesandbox.io/ If it is console logging what you expect then I think we need more code and context. Where is it disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

node modules was corrupted for some reason, never really had that happend to me before, reinstalling rect works! probably my mistake edting the files inside by accident or somthing